Why do I get a difference between two dates in Java?
Period period = new Period(startDate, endDate, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());

int years = period.getYears();
int months = period.getMonths();
int days = period.getDays();

if startDate = May 1, 1975 and endDate April 05, 2024
years = 48, months = 11, days = 4
but if startDate = April 30, 1975 and endDate April 05, 2024
years = 48, months = 11, days = 6
Why is the difference 2 days? expected days = 5! It just doesn’t look so logical when the user, choosing a birthday on the calendar, gets the age (from the current date) for May 1 - 4 days, and for April 30 - 6 days. This looks like an error.
joda time library is used

and is 5/04/2024 supposed to be 04/05/2024?

what period do you get between April 30 and May 1st 1975?

the period is taken between April 30, 1975 and the current date (for example, April 5, 2024) and between May 1, 1975 and again April 5, 2024. The question is that in the first case we get 48 years 11 months and 6 days, and in the second case 48 years 11 months and 4 days! lost one day!

Can you, please, share a complete and verifiable but minimal reproducible example ?  Also, consider adding the [jodatime] tag.

how will this help? you will get the same results. my calculation was that either I made a mistake that would immediately catch your eye, or someone had already encountered a similar problem..

@user414243 no, there's nothing that jumps out, nor is it likely that someone ran into this incredibly esoteric problem before. Especially not within 24 hours or so, and I expect you'd prefer a speedy response. It's not that hard to write a self-contained example, or to do it in plain java (not android) with java.time - if jsr310 (which comes from the same guy that wrote joda-time) does not exhibit this behaviour, that is itself quite interesting information. Write a trivial java class with a main that hardcodes these timestamps of yours and prints the results.

With that code in the question, anybody can simply copy-paste this code and play with it. I'd like to take a stab at it, but your 'I do not see why I should provide a complete example' stance means that you're asking me to do that work. With you asking for free advise, that kind of entitled disrespect means even if I know I'm morally obligated to keep you in the dark. Let's not play these silly games. Retract the question or provide the requested self contained test case.

related question A Bug in java time calculating months between 2 dates - about java.time but seems to be similar problem

Assume that from start date 2 April to end date 2 May is 1 month 0 days. Moving the start 3 days back, to 30 March, should then give us 1 month 3 days. Now also moving the end date 3 days back, to 29 April, we should be back at 1 month 0 days from 30 March to 29 April. Is this what you want? I think not. You need to break your own expectation somewhere.

FYI, the Joda-Time library is in maintenance-mode. The project advises you to migrate to its successor, the java.time classes  built into Java 8+, and defined in JSR 310.

@BasilBourque thanks, but this does not affect the result

@Anonymous oh God no! To understand the essence of the problem, imagine a dialogue with a date picker as calendar and 3 input fields: for year, month and day. By selecting a birthday on the calendar, the fields will be filled in with age (the difference between the current and selected date). Also, by entering your age in reverse order, your birthday will be displayed on the calendar. So, with this calculation of the difference between dates, it looks broken, when by entering an age, you get one birthday, and by indicating the same birthday on the calendar, you get a different age..

This seems perfectly correct to me.
In the first example, where start date is 1/5/1975 - 48 years and 11 months after the start date is 1/4/2024.  From that date, is 4 more days to come to 5/4/2024.  So the difference between 1/5/1975 and 5/4/2024 is 48 years, 11 months and 4 days.
In the second example, where start date is 30/4/1975 - 48 years and 11 months after the start date is 30/3/2024.  From that date, it's 6 more days to come to 5/4/2024.  So the difference between 30/4/1975 and 5/4/2024 is 48 years, 11 month and 6 days.
The reason why a one-day difference in the start date creates a two-day difference in the result is that the "11 months" of the result aren't all the same length.  In particular, in the first example, the 11 months includes March but not April; and in the second example, the 11 months includes April but not March.  Since March and April have different numbers of days, the overall calculation turns out different.

it just doesn’t look so logical when the user, choosing a birthday on the calendar, gets the age (from the current date) for May 1 - 4 days, and for April 30 - 6 days. this looks like an error
